# Why do i get a strange black shadow when i smooth my mesh?

Tags: modeling, shaders

I finished the mesh but went i try to smooth it i got a rare black shadow :

3D viewport - no smooth

[image]

3D viewport -  smooth

[image]

Render - smooth

[image]

Render - no smooth

[image]

Comment: Not an _exact_ duplicate per se of the one marked but the answer applies and seeing that we get at least 1 normals related question a week, it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @iklsR Not a duplicate of that question, rather a duplicate of [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/599).

Comment: @gandalf3 There are so many. Just pick any one, updated tho. Thanks.