# part of my model are see through

Tags: texturing

Every now and then when I am working on a model this happens

[image: them 2 part go see through when i import into UE4]

Why has it become a different color and then when I import it into UE4 they are see through can i fix this or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: Make sure the normals of your mesh are pointing outwards, otherwise UE4 might not draw these faces because of [backface culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).

Comment: recalculate normals : http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15812/11431, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14922/11431 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8325/11431 should help

Comment: Go into edit mode, select all vertices, and press `Ctrl`+`N`

Comment: yessiree. that's the one. yup yup.

Comment: tried to "recalculate answer" as Chebhou asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usally happens when normals are facing the wrong side of the mesh
[image]
Using the backface culling  in the ***N*** panel will make the concerned faces transparent (see-through as in your UE4 game engine)
[image]
You can check your faces normals with this option in the ***N*** panel. This will show you the normals in the viewport.
[image]

To make the normals consistent go in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> (only the bad faces could be enough), and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (recalculate), or  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (recalculate the other direction), or select the faces and click Flip directions
[image]