# I don't know why object has changed color

Tags: color

[image]

Why is the color on the area near the mouth and nose of my model more dark? I can't change it and I don't know what is it. Even when I add texture it is visible.

Comment: check to make sure your [normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27117/2217) are correct.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your screenshot, it seems that your normals are inconsistent. To fix this,  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  into *edit mode*, then select everything by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>  twice,(assuming nothing is already selected in the scene) and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> to make your normals consistent.

You can usually tell if your normals have been flipped because the shading on your object will darken.