# 2.8 Bake unexpected results

Tags: modeling

I am trying to learn how to bake in Blender 2.8 with a simple cube. I have followed multiple tutorials but the result is always the same. See attached images.

[image: Normals]

[image: Ambient Occlusion]

[image: defuse]

The normals are all pointing outwards and I have tried with a multitude of lights and none. I have tried all baking options but I still get more or less the same result with black areas where there are none in the render.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to bake?

Comment: A cube as in the first image

Answer (score 0):

I added an hdri environment background which fixed the issue. Thanks for the anonymous downvote.

[Weird Black "Shadows" On Rendered Image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24746/weird-black-shadows-on-rendered-image?rq=1)