# Mesh appears purple after join

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

After I joined together a mirrored joined duplicate into one single mesh, the duplicated mesh becomes purple:

[image: Before and after]

What is going on here? Do I need to be worried about this? When joining the roof with the base of the building, this doesn't happen.

Comment: where is the purple ( usually a missing texture ) ?

Comment: The whole other half of the roof becomes purple, it's pretty easy to see in the picture.

Comment: try  "Recalculate Normals"  "Ctrl+N" in edit mode, (still can't see the purple)

Comment: there are related answers to this question, but I can't find the question as being asked this way anywhere: but related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/dark-regions-due-to-smooth-shading

Comment: @Chebhou It's... well maybe it's not purple, perhaps it's more like dark grey.

Comment: think of it as a solved problem color : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in face colours is an indicator that the direction of those faces are not uniform.

[image]

Enter edit mode and look for the side panel submenu called "Mesh Display"

[image]

In the normals subheading, select the face icon. Lines (called *normals*) will start to emit from each face. I've adjusted the `size` slider so those lines aren't ridiculously large or small. The thing to note here is that if you don't see the line emitting from some faces, that those faces are flipped.

To make them uniform press <kbd>cltr</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get the faces menu and *Recalc normals*   (Or Directly using Ctrl+N)

This makes the mesh faces point in a uniform way, and the colour difference will go away:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that I had to flip normals myself before your answer appeared. I have still marked it as it's the right answer =)