# Why are the mesh faces different colors?

Tags: faces

In the 3D View window the mesh I am modeling appears with two different colors.  The final render has one color.

it's my first day learning blender and I'm following a tutorial to create a house model. In the tutorial the different faces of the house are all the same color, but my faces are having two different colors. I'm wondering why was there a color applied and what does it mean? When I render the model it's all the same color.

[image: different face colors]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't tell you why they're in this state currently, as there are many possible reasons, these colors indicated the direction in which the face normals point. To fix this, you need to recalculate your faces' normals, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. Alternatively, this can be done from the toolbar (whose visibility is toggled by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>),by pressing *Recalculate* found in the *Shading/UVs* tab of said toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make sure your [normals] are consistent.

In the image above the 3D View is in edit mode.  Normals are displayed as thin blue lines and you see the panel to show this with the word [Normals].  You can see one Normal has intentionally been flipped/changed.  The material panel is shown so I know I have only one material.

[image]