# Why is this object completely black while in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

My object in Edit mode has gone completely black in edit mode, and I cannot seem to correct it.  I was following a tutorial at the Lyndia site working through a UV example, and I never went much further than unwrapping the object, and it did not appear to be the same object the tutorial was illustrating and eventually got to this state trying to remove extra vertices that were showing up.  I also tried to remove the seams, but cannot even add them nom

I am going to start the project again, but I would like to know what happened, so I do not do it a gain unless I need to.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
Thanks

[image: Edit Mode - Hammer Object Black]

Comment: Can you upload your blend file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so that it's easier to diagnose what's wrong?

Comment: Blend file uploaded.

Comment: I'm not sure why and how it was done, but if you remove doubles (Edit mode > select all > `W` > *Remove doubles*) ~ 2000 verts will be removed. After recalculating normals (`Ctrl`+`N`) mesh should be good. Still I didn't experienced *black* mesh - it was slightly different than usual one.

Comment: @MrZak That seems to solve it. Care to post this as an answer?

Comment: @MrZak I was able to correct the object follow your steps.  I believe the how and why could be largely related to me being new to Blender and my Mac.   At the end I may have tried one to many things before posting the file.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case mesh is built with too many vertices and faces serving no purpose for this not complex mesh. Initially it has slightly more than ~2000 polygons which is too much for that.

[image: Initial mesh]

1. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove doubles*. It will tell you that around 2000 double vertices was removed.
2. Select all if not selected and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals. The model will look as usual from now on.

   [image: Mesh after execution]

Read about normals: [Why are some of faces in my mesh darker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: @RobertRhodes One last thing to add (not related to *this* problem but important in future) - it's good idea to apply scale in Object mode using `Ctrl`+`A`. Read more about that [in this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Ironically the presenter of the tutorial covered that next.  I am still not grasping the problem, but I will read through your material and keep and eye out for it.  Thanks.