# Is this normal?

Tags: shadows

I wonder if that´s normal. When I smooth my mesh it looks kinda odd. If it´s not supposed to do that...[image]what am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. However that's not the only problem, I'm not sure how to achieve that, try turning off modifiers and working with mesh itself. Remove doubles, try suggestions from linked question. It could happen that retopologizing is easier in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You´ve been really quick! :D I´ll try what you suggest. Wish me good luck lol.

Comment: Yep, it was only that :D :D :D Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Is there any problem with your answer that I can´t punctuate it?

Comment: What do you mean ? If answer in linked question solved your problem then most likely your question has already been answered. Hence this should be a duplicate.

Comment: @MatCav, there is not yet an answer to this question; just a comment trail.

Comment: I am sorry, but no, that is not normal. great title BTW

Comment: problems with normals are totally normal. so yes. normal problems are normal.