# Merged characters hand to the arm and got a weird choppy result

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

Looking for a smooth transition
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Blender.SE! You should provide more details in order to get useful answer, .e.g screenshot of mesh in Edit mode, how did you model and join meshes, do they have any modifiers. You could [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your blend to get more help with your particular problem. Try to enter Edit mode and remove doubles (select all > `W` > *Remove Doubles*). You might want to take a [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to get more idea how to use this site.

Comment: @MrZak
I Removed Doubles as you suggested, but the choppy transition stays the same.
As for Modifiers I have Subdivision Surface and Mirror active.
I joined the meshes by merging vertexes in the center between them.
![More images](https://i.gyazo.com/352d33e8ab7a5ed34224b739f07eeac7.png).

Comment: In Edit mode select all and press `Ctrl`+`N` to recalculate normals. Note that they may be flipped instead of becoming consistent, while the goal is to get rid of black faces like on your top screenshot. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: @MrZak That worked perfectly, the normals was indeed flipped! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Normals was inverted,
you can flip normals of selected faces while in Edit mode by:

3D Viewport Header -> Mesh -> Faces -> Flip Normals

If you want to quickly fix all the normals in your mesh, while in Edit mode you can use Recalculate Normals:

- 3D Viewport Header -> Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside (CTRL + N)
- 3D Viewport Header -> Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Inside (SHIFT + CTRL + N)

  > [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Thanks to Mr Zak & Thom Blair III

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24596)

Comment: @PGmath Thanks for the feedback, hope it's looking ok now.