# Why is part of the object a different color than everything else?

Tags: modeling

[image: PaganiZonda]

So today I got on blender for the first time in a long time and decided that if I was every going to get better I would need to start practicing modeling and such. I decided I would model a Pagani Zonda to see what I could do. One of the mirrors on the car is a different color from everything else and I would like to know why. I haven't started texturing yet (though I'm not sure if I will because the model isn't that good). I wish I could describe it better. Is there a way I can post the file? I don't know how to do that sorry. I'm pretty bad at computers. Thanks in advance!

*Update* I figure out how to add an image at least. It's kind of hard to see but the left mirror is a weird color and I don't know why.

Comment: You can upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your question. Have you tried recalculating your normals? `Ctrl + N` with the mesh selected in *edit mode*.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Answer (score 1):

The normals are inside out. You need to flip normals. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in edit mode.