# Why does mesh imported into Unity can be seen through?

Tags: import, unity

I made simple funny character in blender without animations. In Blender it looks good, this is the screenshot of it:
[image]

When i put my character.blend file into Unity assets folder, it says

```
"Meshes may not have more than 65534 vertices or triangles at the moment.  
Mesh 'Plane' will be split into 2 parts: 'Plane_MeshPart0', 'Plane_MeshPart1'".
```

Also in Unity my character was cut down at joining of the legs and body as shown in figure.
[image: This image taken from unity 5]

How to import .blend file into Unity and avoid these artifacts ?
Which format should I use ?

Comment: Recalculate normals on the mesh (`Ctrl`+`N` with all selected), see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. I'm not sure what does Unity warning mean, if it's not caused by normals then probably you should ask it on Unity forums.