# What is happening here? Boolean modifier works *almost*

Tags: modifiers

[image: Hollow out a sphere]

So I want to hollow out a spheroid.
I redo the normals, extrude inwards, use p to separate the smaller spheroid copy, extrude its faces only outwards, move it into another layer, then use a boolean to subtract this from the original (big) spheroid. You see the result. It works *almost*.

Why not completely? What am I doing wrong? The smaller sphere's protrusions definitely go fully beyond the bigger sphere on both sides, inside and outside.

Here is the file for download: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41696

Comment: It would be easier if you added only screenshots instead of gif in order to make post clearer. One reason for bad results of Boolean can be flipped normals; enter Edit mode for spheroid and press `Ctrl`+`N` with all selected, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. You might want to [upload this file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for convenience.

Comment: Thank you, I already aligned the normals. I will upload the file momentarily

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41696 Here it is

Comment: What was the original mesh like (before Boolean) ?  As for now subtracted mesh has good amount of Ngons and inverted normals. If that was present while using modifier the result won't be expectable. *Note*: do you want to get effect of [wire-like mesh](http://i.imgur.com/DW7UspX.gif) ?

Comment: Before it was just a solid body with 12 faces. I used the answer from TLousky to get exactly what I wanted.

No, it was not a wire-like mesh - it has to be solid (from all sides) to be suitable for 3d printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the new (blender 2.76+) intersect (boolean) feature.
[image]

Steps to recreate:

1. Go to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
2. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>).
3. Extrude inwards (<kbd>E</kbd>).
4. Go to Face select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).
5. Extrude individual (Tools panel-->Add-->Extrude Individual) outwards.
6. Select entire inner mesh island (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>).
7. Open dynamic spacebar menu (<kbd>Space</kbd>).
8. Type in "Intersect (Boolean)" and confirm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description. It worked way better than what I did before.
Oh, and it solved my problem :)
I've been trying for five hours today to find a solution or workaround. Thanks!