# Boolean modifier not catching the mesh properly

Tags: modifiers

When i try to use boolean Union to add one mesh to another it appears that evrything is alright but when i apply and then try to move it, it only catches a part of it

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image]

Could someone Help me?

## EDIT

I just noticed that if i move the object a little away from the Main Object it works...

But still doens't resolve my problem because i want that peace to be there...

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Recalculate normals in Edit mode (`Ctrl`+`N`), probably for both objects. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker.

Comment: You do realize, that you actually don't need to use Boolean to join meshes in terms of "add one mesh to another"? It's quite hard to see what you actually want to "union" in your screenshots. Consider uploading your blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I tryied to recalculate the normals and it worked thank you