# problem while exporting the model to unity

Tags: unity, .fbx

Hey guys i'm new to blender and recently i was working on my model but i'm facing a problem when i export it has fbx and load it in unity

[image: here is how the object looks when i'm in blender]

This is how the object looks when i'm in blender
and This is how the object looks in unity

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Recalculate normals. Read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: Yep, looks like a normals issue