# Why does mesh have dark faces and is destroyed with Subsurf modifier?

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, shaders

This glitch is really annoying me and I'm not sure how to fix it.
I am making a character with no current textures or materials and I've been trying everything to fix it. I am using blender 2.76. I have provided pictures below. It looks prominent in Rendered and Material shading mode. It looks fine in Solid shading mode. It is also prominent when applying a Subdivision Surface modifier (which I am going to do later on anyway).

Thanks in advance.

[image: Solid View]

[image: Subdivision Surface Modifer]

This is the rendered view:

Comment: Go to Edit Mode > Press A to select All, then in the panel on the left side Shading > Recalculate Normals

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. Not sure if it's a dup of it as the question in this case is different.