# Backface culling from blender to unity

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export, unity

I've got a finished model which is made up of circles on top of circles with a cylinder on the bottom, trying to resemble a pine tree.
[image: This is the pine tree.]

When i export the model as .fbx with the 6.1 ACII to unity, the model shows up in a wierd way and i have no idea why and how to fix it. It looke like this:
[image: This is how it shows up in unity]

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try checking normals (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) and apply transforms (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data). If it doesn't help please [provide your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can preview the backface culling in Blender with the check box in the shading panel. To fix your problem, just tab into edit mode, then hit Ctrl + N to recalculate normals.

[image]

Comment: I already found the solution, I needed to do what you said and then solidify the mesh so that the inner faces are visible,  now the outer and inner faces can be seen with no problem.  @MrZak

Comment: You actually don't need to solidify the mesh. This adds unnecessary geometry (that isn't good for game engines like Unity); please see my gif.

Comment: I already saw it but I also need the inner faces visible (like if you were looking under the tree) and flipping the normals only makes the outer faces (when you see the tree from the front) visible on the mesh and I need both inner and outer, thanks for your help anyways, it speed up the process of figuring it out.

Comment: The fact is, Game engines uses the Backface Culling to speed up their real-time render engine.  You had to enable the double-sided feature in 3D game engines or create the solidified model so you do not see any culled parts.  Blender had no part in this.