# Mapping an orthographic texture to a model

Tags: texturing, uv, orthographic

I created a model, that is based on an orthographic projection. The orthographic projection also contains the image(s) that I want to map to my model. (Ship model left / Orthographic view and textures right)

[image: Ship model left / Orthographic view and textures right]

I was hoping that there was a way to map this model directly as it is (Model made based off of the projection) to the orthographic view without having to individually map each part to the image. I was able to apply the side view texture to the corresponding side, but when I try to map any other angle, it replaces my old texture. This is what I was able to achieve:

[image: Ship with partial texture applied]

As you can see, when I mapped one side, the top, and all other sides were replaced with what has left over from that side map instead of the part I mapped earlier (I used 'Project From View'). So I was wondering how I could map my model based off of this orthographic projection. Also, this is the only texture that I could obtain, so I won't be able to edit this image in order to change it to match a specific UV map. I would appreciate a precise step by step walkthrough (if possible) on how to accomplish this task.

Note: Using Cyles Render (can't use Blender Render for specific parts in this project) on Blender v2.76

Comment: Surfaces that exist in more than one view will create a problem if you just **unwrap from view**,  you have to choose then which projection to use for  each part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last piece which is missing in your setup is that *Project From View* like any other UV unwrap method unwraps *all* the mesh parts which are selected.

As you selected the whole mesh and unwrapped it, its UV map was created according to that point of view - for the whole object (so there are intersecting parts on that UV map island you have shown in your screenshot).
The problem is that you want only side of the object to be unwrapped according to that projection and it is very likely that you want the front part of the object to be unwrapped with *Project From View* executed once your view is oriented accordingly. E.g. this famous person uses UV map made with *Project From View* executed from the front view:

[image: screenshot of monkey which doesn't look good from the side]

It looks relatively good from the front view, but the side view is distorted as much as it was visible from the point of view when unwrapping.
So if you want to use *Project From View*, select only adjacent parts of the mesh according to what is visible while unwrapping, or mark seams and unwrap according to them (the view point won't make any difference then).

Comment: I was able to fix my problem with my mapping, but now there is a seam that is dividing where I connected the top and side view textures. The textures match up, but the brightness changes (The top is darker, and the bottom is lighter). So I was wondering if there was a way to remove that seam in Blender without editing my original image. (I know it is not because of lighting because I am not in rendered view, and currently have no lamps)

Comment: @TomW probably [normals are pointing in the wrong direction](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) on those faces or texture has different brightness.., but that's guessing. You should ask a new question about that problem and provide context (like images and etc).