# (noob here) odd discoloration on my model, what does it mean?

Tags: objects

[image]

(model is not nearly complete btw)

whenever go into the mode that makes the faces solid (idk what it's called), some parts of my model are discolored (sort of steel-blue looking). i was curious as to why that was happening and if that is going to be carried out into a final render. thanks for any help that yall can offer :))

bonus question: what's the best/easiest way to add more detail/make a model less blocky? besides adding a load of loop cuts obviously lol. thanks

Comment: recalculate your normals. In edit mode press ctrl+n to make normals consistent.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Answer (score 1):

your normals are not all facing outwards, in general its a problem of the mesh recalculating them is the easiest way to solve it.
If that doesnt work out (if your model isnt solid), you can also in edit mode flip faces.

Answer (score 1):

For your bonus question:  While in *Object mode,* tap <kbd>T</kbd>
select *Shading:* **Smooth**

You can press <kbd>T</kbd> again to close that panel.

Add an *Edge Split* modifier.  This will keep edges sharp,
even if the rest of the model is painted with a smooth rounded appearance.

[image: EdgeSplit]

Comment: the edge split modifier was exactly what i was looking for thanks