# why does a random object extremely shiny?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

this is the first time this has happened, i'm in the beginning stages of texturing and all but when i went to preview the render the second pad from the top was extremely shiny and i cant figure out why, iv used the same texture on all the pads and this is the only one to be like this. when i'm not in render mode the object is a different colour than the rest as well, how do i fix this? [image]

Comment: "The object is of different colour" sounds like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. Try selecting all in Edit mode and pressing Ctrl+N.

Comment: Please add images that show the settings for the material.