# Weird lines across the mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting, subdivision-surface

I have the mesh subdivided a lot of times but it doesn't solve it..And the subdivision surface doesn't do anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it appears thet the faces of your mesh are facing inwards: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: They aren't I have checked!

Comment: Di you select smooth shading in the left menu?

Comment: Yes! I think I have found the problem....but it makes no sense...I have subdivided the mesh and then added the subdivision surface.I shouldn't have subdivided the mesh, I think they dont work very well together