# Subsurface Causing Mesh Problems

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

Just started using blender, and naturally the first thing I'm making is a minigun. It looks dope.

Problem is, when I applied the subsurface modifier, I ran into a problem.
[image]

And without it...
Nothing.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Heres the link to the .blend files: https://www.mediafire.com/?1iq489br01zej02

Edit: It can be somewhat fixed by changing the number of subdivisions, but this makes it WAY to high quality.

Comment: Looks no problem when open the file here

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for more permanent blend file uploads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: You have many overlapping loopcuts in those areas, instead of doing that maybe try to inset the ribs to add crease

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the model and found your problem. You've got hundreds or vertices on top of each other.

[image]

What you want to do is select everything live I've done and press <kbd>W</kbd> to open the specials menu and press "Remove doubles".

[image]

As you can see, you've lost all your sharpness in your mesh. You we're probably extruding faces to make these infinitely thin ones that gave you sharp edges, but there's a better way.

What you want to do when you find an edge you want to sharpen it select it and by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to go into edge crease mode and sharpen edges by pulling your cursor from the edge's origin.

[image]
Here you can see I hot a little too excited and did a bunch of edges.

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>z</kbd> to activate wireframe, you will likely notice that there is a high density of triangles where you are seeing that phenomena.  This is also probably why you see it get better/worse when you mess with subsurf's detail level.

You will have to mess with your topology in order for this to go away.  It is otherwise a harmless effect. If you do your UV's well, you won't even notice when you finally texture the model.