# Strange clipping with the mesh

Tags: mesh

So I made this cushion but it has this weird clipping or shading on the cushion part.

Here it is without subdivision smoothness and also with it. Any ideas how I can begin fixing this?

[image]

[image]

[image: This was after i went through and individually deleted each double face]

This was after i went through and deleted any double faces individually. Not sure why remove doubles didnt catch them. Still doesnt look right.

Comment: And before you ask i already removed doubles so its not a double mesh issue.

Comment: There shouldn't be necessarily doubles to make the mesh look wrong. Start with recalculating normals, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/1245. Then likely it is [non-manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/1245) where those grey parts seen trough cushion are faces of the bottom part not connected to anything. Some rebuilding and cleaning work will be required to change that mesh

Comment: It does look like  z-fighting due to duplicated geometry.

Comment: Please use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to share files on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks like two meshes. May be a duplicate, hidden in Viewport, but visible while rendering? If you can't solve the issue, consider uploading your blend file.

Edit: After checking your file, it's clear that overlapping faces are the reason for your problems. Look at the screenshots, I raised some part of your mesh. You need to remodel your mesh, to avoid intersecting faces.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do I upload my file? I tried the normals thing and it didnt work. And I went in and removed doubles again and says 0 vertices removed so Im still having the issue.

Comment: I uploaded my file to this site. 

https://we.tl/i0FoR0K08O

thanks!

Comment: So I went through and started deleting individual faces and there were doubles. Not sure why it didnt catch it automatically. I went through the whole top layer and removed all the double faces but it still looks wrong.

Comment: I edited my answer after checking your file.