# how do you light dark areas

Tags: modeling, lighting

okay so, my lighting is being weird and I have several dark spots, it doesn't matter how many lights i have or where i move them, they still persist, its also bugging me that the gloves are the exact same material as the white spots on the shoes, but are look darker.
I've tried changing the environmental lighting too, but it doesn't help
[image]

Comment: The faces on the gloves are looking to the opposite side (inwards) see this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably shading. In the properties>data tick a box that says "Auto Smooth" and try an angle like 30.