# What does it mean that part of my mesh is darker grey in edit mode? Boolean Problems

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have been editing a mesh I created after importing an svg and using it as a boolean to cut into a plane. The plane needed lots of work to get rid of extra verts.

As I was deleting and dissolving, I noticed that parts of the plane were darker grey. When I got rid of a few extraneous verts, it turned lighter grey, which I took to be a sign that I was doing good.

But, I have parts that I can't get to turn lighter grey. If I knew what I was changing or what Blender was warning about, it would help me to formulate a better plan for decimating this mesh cleanly.

I have checked the normals and recalculated, flipped and set from faces etc, but I don't know what is going on.

Thanks[image: ![Different greys in the edit window]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mK4I.jpg)

Comment: Probably your "Normal" is facing the wrong way. *On a side note you should be working towards modeling with faces that have four sides.

Comment: You could add your .blend file to your question here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If the normals are correct you might have the same face twice at the same spot. This is possible in bmesh, even after you removed double vertices.

Comment: @Dimali, I think you are correct. I used BMesh. Is there an easy way to figure that out? Remove Doubles doesn't seem to touch it. And, if I grab that plane with the face select, the whole dark grey area moves. There is probably one or two verts that are making it two faces on top.

Comment: @Dontwalk Yeah, I know about the 4 sides. I need to subdivide this plane up manually to get back to that. The orginal mesh was just too complex. I haven't uploaded it bc I ran out of time. Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: Nope, this isn't about normals. It's about duplicate faces on top of each other. And, I think, sharing a few vertices, enough so it is hard to find the duplicates.

Comment: Right click on the face and delete it. If there is still a face, then you have duplicate faces.

Comment: @dimali that was my thought as well. However, in this case, it didn't work. Deleting the face took out that whole section of mesh. I think it was because there were just those two edges that were not correct. I wanna say that it was all one face that was folded over itself. And it wasn't correct until I deleted the two edge segments. That unfolded it.

Comment: Even if you chose "Delete Faces only"?

Comment: Hmmm... I think that I had tried that and was surprised when it took out the whole section. But, that was a week ago now. And my frustration trying to fix that mesh was reaching "Hulk smash" proportions, so I don't remember. I know that parts of that mesh had strange topology after running the Boolean op. In trying to clean up, I may have caused the folds myself with dissolving and decimating verts to try and simplify things so it would render w/o choking my machine.

Answer (score 1):

@Dimali was correct, there appears to be two faces on top of each other that share MOST of the same edges, but not these two.

[image: Duplicated edges.]

I discovered this after trying to select the edge loop and those two would not be included.

[image: Edge loop selection]

Deleting those two turns the mesh a uniform grey.

[image]

[image]

Now, the edgeloops go all the way around and I can start making quads by grabbing two vertices and using J

[image]

there is probably a simpler way to "quadify" this but I haven't figured it out yet.

[image]

Comment: Does, say, Bridge Edge Loops work for "quadification"?

Comment: Wish I could answer that @seaturtle. I haven't tried bridge edge loop function yet.

Comment: @seaturtle it does that by default for the most part...
IF both of your edge loops have the same number of verts / edges selected, then this will work, as soon as you deviate, it will most likely triangulate.