# Normals not working?

Tags: materials, objects, light, normals

so im making this skull/brain thingy. i make the skull and imported the brain. and as you can see are the faces on the brain much darker. i fixed the normals and imported it to unity where i could se all the faces but the brain was still "wierd". i cant seem to figure out a way to make the brain and skull look the same look. notice the shadow on the brain in unity looks kinda metalic

[image]

[image: In Blender]

[image: In Unity]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: Since your normals seem to be pointing outside, it's hard to give advice. So consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen somethimes that the tool to correct the normals (Ctrl+N, normals_make_consistent)  puts all the normal inside. It is usually linked to a bad topology.

A quick way to fix that is to flip all the normals (they are consistent, but all in the wrong direction).

To do that

- go to edit mode
- select all vertices
- press space and search for "Flip normals" Or hit ctrl+f and chose Flip Normals