# Can't perform boolean difference with an imported collada object

Tags: modifiers, import, collada

I imported a Collada file created on Photoshop (turning a png into 3d plane), then extruded it in Blender.
The reason for that is that this is a complex object to create with curves myself so I figured it's a faster approach.

Then I try to cut through some objects with this extrusion using the boolean modifier - difference, but I never seem to get this to work properly. Either getting "Cannot execute boolean operation" or it just won't cut the objects at all.

Tried modifying the boxes with the imported object as target, and the other way around too...
I tried to use the knife project by selecting a box and the imported project but I get an error on "no other selected objects for projection" error.
I tried removing doubles and fixing the normals.
Nothing helped so far...

Here's the Blender file - [image]

What can I fix for that to work?
This is my first Blender project btw...
Please don't mark as duplicate because I already mentioned that I perofrmed the actions described in other posts and it didn't help.

[image: screenshot of project]

Comment: Welcome to [bse](https://blender.stackexchange.com) Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files.  Paste All files will be removed after time making the link dead for future readers of this question.

Comment: unfortunately it's not a duplicate... I already checked all other occurrences of this matter before posting. Also I updated the link to the blender file.

Comment: It seems to be working in the .blend file you uploaded. You realize that after you Apply the Boolean Modifier your bull/buffalo object will still be there. You need to hide it and move it to another layer/ turn render for it off or delete it.

Comment: I accidentally uploaded the wrong file. Now uploaded the correct file relevant to the question. The file I uploaded by mistake included an object created from curves, but the file I am referring to (which is now available in the link above) contains the imported object I referred to in the question. Thanks for notifying me...

Comment: The bull has incosistent normals. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: I already mentioned in the original post that I fixed the normals. Is there anything I missed?