# Same material different result within object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

**Prologue:**
Minor issue that I do not seem to figure out, I've modeled room with some basic things that i've created from the scratch but now there is weird issue with wallpaper material.

[image: Room with wallpaper material displaying differently on opposite wall]

[image: View in edit mode, for object positions]

**Description:**
All of the 3 walls are part of the same box object, they have same material and they have been uv mapped the same way on same scale yet the wall on the right displays on grey color instead of the white like the 2 others.

**Steps taken:**
I've deleted the wall with the issue, recreated it, uv mapped the whole thing again and ended up with the same results. Also went through recreating the material with same result. Checked the direction of normals.

**Plea for help:**
Any ideas what might cause this, still new to the cycles so would appreciate the insight to the problem so I can learn from it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [your normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: I've checked the normals, all of the faces are properly facing towards the center of the room.

The model is properly showing up in viewport but the issue persists on rendering.

Comment: @Brenticus, Non-color data is expected for normal map textures. Actually Color texture mode should only be used for diffuse, any other shader or effect using a texture should use Non-Color.

Comment: Where is the light positioned in the scene? Can you share your blender file?

Comment: In the UV map where is the closet wall? Is it the same object? Did you applie scale to the objects prior to unwrapping? How did you unwrap?

Comment: @Bruno, I added image of the viewport to display the lights and such, I'll add link later for sharing it when I'm at my pc.

Comment: @cegaton, In the first image you see uv at bottom left, the closet wall is on the right and the doors are just floating boxes next to it, tried removing those also. I've applied all and unwrap was last thing i did, I used project from view for each wall and scaled them as seen in image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
After fiddling around for while with the issue, recreating and mapping the room also redoing the material and lights ending up with the same problem. The solution to the problem was adding a **normal map node in between the Image texture and Diffuse BSDF**

**Result:**
[image: Fixed render and material settings]

Thank you everyone for input, hope this helps out someone in the future.