# Wierd artifact on my mug

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

Can someone explain why i got this strange "artifact". I'm following a tutorial.

[image]

Comment: have you checked this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: Use built-in facility to include images please so they are in the question body, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post as your post relies on information from image completely

Comment: It looks like it may be extra geometry. Tab into Edit Mode and press ALT + "H" to un-hide everything to see if there is unwanted geometry there.