# Parts of my model are a different color to the rest

Tags: objects

I have a Problem with my first Blender model. As you can see in the images, the color of the legs are different to the rest of the model:

[image]
[image]

I haven't applied any modifiers besides the *Subdivision Surface* and *Mirror*.

Can anybody tell why it looks like that and how I can change it to the normal solid look?

Answer (score 0):

okay i already got it  by extruding the mesh it with e (like duplicating).
notice that you should mark all faces, if you have the same problem. 
llink to discription: [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Answer (score 0):

The normal of your mesh are pointing in the wrong direction, in this case inwards instead of outwards. The easiest, most clean way to fix this is by going into Edit mode, then Shading/UV Tab and click on Recalculate normals with all the mesh selected.