# Change of color after I join meshes with Ctrl+J

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders

I've made a vase which has 2 handles. The handles were created separately so I wanted to join them and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to do so, with the intention to then trim the unneeded vertexes.

But as I join all in a single mesh there's a change in color, like it's no longer being lit properly. What's causing this and how can I fix it?

[image: Left is Joined Right is not]

<sup>*Left Joined, right not joined*</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: In most cases this happens when one of joined objects had inverted (negative) scale, just in case for future handling with meshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a normals problem. You need to flip normals.

Select the whole mesh in edit mode, then go to *mesh*, *normals*, and *recalculate outside.*

Refer to this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks that solved it now I can work on the inside of the vase!