# Subdivide problem

Tags: modeling

Can you tell me what Subdivide problem is?

I combined the models in one. Select all <kbd>A</kbd> in Edit mode, then I split the surface with Subdivide. Some surfaces does not want to divide.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: can you provide the file?

Comment: With the bridge edge loops it can be possible. Delete the mark faces and the side faces. With the top and the bottom faces press space bar and type bridge edge loops. Then you can sub-dived and add extra loops. Yes if file is provided maybe you get a detail answer.

Comment: Also be sure you have all vertices connected (select all and -> W -> remove doubles)

Comment: @Crantisz File here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdv4xn7tlyuan3q/knights_subdivided.blend?dl=0

Comment: @Marcell First, you have many unconnected vertices - select all and hit W->Remove Doubles. Also your mesh consists of n-gons and with such uneven geometry, you cannot expect any regular subdivision. So you I am pretty sure you have to clean model's geometry (use CleanUp function - dissolve, triangulate etc.) before you can subdivide it nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This vertexes prevent face from subdividing, because this is n-gon (more than 4 vertexes on one face), N-gons cannot be subdivided.

[image]

To remove them do this (**with original model before subdividing**):

1. Select one of this vertexes
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> **Amount of adjacent faces**
3. Then <kbd>X</kbd> -> **Dissolve vertexes**

After you clean model, you can subdivide it.

If it doesn't helps, remove excess vertexes manually

You need to fix another problem on your mesh, see also:
[Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: Thank you for the tips! And thank you for a link (my mesh darker). I found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

Because of many edges, can't create subdivision.

1. Select problematic edges (Edit Mode)
2. Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> -> Limited Dissolve
3. Subdividing and done!

Thanks for your supporters!

[image: how subdividing]