# strange modeling issue in simple modeling (blender 2.80Beta)

Tags: modeling

I am getting this weight artifacts on some edges while modeling a simple horse - I have tried deleting the the whole patch and redoing it but it keeps coming back - could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

[image: Blender modeling issue]

Here is the Blender file (2.80Beta) [image]

Comment: That's what I thought - tried remove-doubles also - but it's not resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was a normal issue. Got resolved by recalculating the normal (Shift+N in Blender 2.80)

This thread describes it in detail:
[Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Thank you Duarte!