# Blender material issue while snapping two objects snaps together

Tags: materials

[image]
[image]

This is two half-sphere snap to each other by the center line.
I am working on a modeling project which run into this problem.

I want to make it like a whole sphere while render it out, but it like this

[image]

The vertex at the center line are perfectly aligned.

And I would like to keep it two objects.

Is there any way to make it like one single object but without that center line?

Comment: Do you just want to cut 1/4th of the circle with faces inside?

Comment: What about boolean modifier?

Comment: Could you post a link to download the .blend file so we can have a look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two reasons here for discontinuous smooth shading.

1. The normals are flipped on the right half ... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > <kbd>F</kbd>, Flip normals
2. The normals haven't got anything to interpolate to over the edges of the hemispheres.

To fix (2), retain an intact version of the sphere as a form, same topology, same location, and transfer the normals from it to the 2 halves, by giving them  Data Transfer modifiers, with the intact sphere as target, and the settings shown. You will have to set 'Autosmooth' on the hemispheres in their data tabs.

[image]