# why is there a gradient on my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

[image]

There's a gradient on some parts of my mesh. I tried flipping the normals, and it wasn't doing anything. Is there a way to remove the gradient?

Comment: Can you go to vertex mode and check that there isn't a couple of hidden ones that make your face partly hidden by another rogue one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)