# Help!! 3d mesh with black lines. Retopology

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was practicing 3D doing retopology when I went to smooth the mesh, I ended up finding this black line.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)