# Mesh Has Black Faces and Recalculate Normals Outside (Ctrl+N) Change Nothing

Tags: mesh, normals

everyone.

I'm still "intermediate" in Blender.
I usually mod 3D model from TESIV:Oblivion game.
Know a bit about: importing, exporting, cutting mesh, UV mapping, bone weighting, etc.
But haven't learn to make 3D model from 0.

Usually, there's commmunity that likes to rip 3D model from games.
And so, I import .obj file to Blender 2.49b, but found this issue on the mesh:
[image]

Anybody know how to fix it?

(I follow this link: [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) but nothing change)

Comment: That's likely just because of the smooth shading and a strong angle between the faces. BTW is there any reason why you're working in the ancient 2.49b? The never versions also have a .obj importer.

Comment: Try to turn on, auto smooth, and play with the edge angle.

Comment: @Robert Gützkow I tried the latest version of Blender and update python...but that makes me cannot modding TESIV:Oblivion because of certain error like cannot import Oblivion's nif file. Since I work a lot with Oblivion, so I'm still stick with the "ancient" 2.49b.

Comment: @SaifMohamd I'll see what I can do about the edge angle. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @SaifMohamd Know any tutorials for Blender 2.49b about this problem?

Comment: is there no AutoSmooth Option in blender 2.49b ? dit you see this here ?
https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/430981-smooth-mesh-modelling-tips/

Comment: Yes there is. But Smoothing is not the case here, because the mesh already set to smooth; not solid. I saw that link. But still no solution about Face Normals. In Blender Edit Mode, there's option: Normals > Flip. But why no option: Normals > Face?! And so, I think what I did with NifSkope is the thing that Blender can't do. Idk...if somebody know there's that feature in Blender 2.49b, please inform here. So far, the solution is using NifSkope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution!
Use NifSkope, right-click on the mesh, choose Mesh > Face Normals.

[image]