# Adding solidify mesh getting sharp edge

Tags: modifiers

I want to add solidify modifier to give thickness.

[image]

**With Solidify modifier** Getting this result

[image]

**Without solidify modifier** result is good but some sharp edge seen (mark in white)

[image]

Want to have some thickness but without this all above issue. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: 1) Recalculate normals on your base mesh.  2) Enable merge on your array and tune the distance (should be some very very low value, like 0.001)

Comment: @Nathan superb thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)

Comment: @brockmann Above i have thanks to Nathan it solved with recalculate normals

Comment: that's the point of the dupe. And nathan won't answer so we can close it I think... @atek