# Faces don't look smooth when using shade smooth

Tags: faces

I'm working on a human mesh, and I wanted to Shade Smooth it, but for some reason it looks weird around the shins.

[image]

This has happened twice, the active face seems to gets messed up when using shade smooth. Why is this happening? There's a way to fix this, right?

Comment: Looks very similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker/3615#3615

Comment: Click the Object Data Properties (green triangle) icon on the R/H properties panel, then click 'Normals' and check Auto Smooth.